# Can MS Access handle multiple many-to-many relationships across more than 2 tables

Tags: ms-access, many-to-many

I have 2 similar databases with the following tables:

Table 1 - Invoices

Table 2 - Invoice Line (intermediate - primary invoice -> primary product)

Table 3 - Products

Table 4 - Services (or Products 2)

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship.  I understand the need for an intermediate table for 1-to-many/1-to-many.

The issue is:
With the Invoices table I need to have a many-to-many relationship not just with products table but also the services table (or a 2nd set of products table with my other database).

I'm assuming with a services table database, I could create a 2nd intermediate table (invoice -> services)  But wouldn't this create 2 seperate subform related tables?  Rather than just 1 related subform with a list of all products and all services together.

Also, in the case where the invoice would just be a list of products from 2 different product tables (perhaps using a composite key on both product tables "prdA-xx" and "prdB-xx" so there are no duplicate primary keys across both tables?)

I'm hoping there is a single solution for both issues?

While I could combine the 2 separate product tables, since each table comes from different suppliers with thousands of records each, I need to keep them separate for different requirements, some different fields and normaliziation.

The expected solution will have a single invoice with multiple products from one table and multiple (services or products) from the 2nd table all together hopefully in 1 related subform if possible since the basic fields needed will be the same:  "desc, price, qty"

Answer (score 0):

You may have a misunderstanding of what a many-to-many relationship actually is. Anyway here is how I would deal with the different products tables: I would create a query using UNION, that would make all the separate tables work as one. Short example:

```
SELECT Supplier1ID AS ProductID, Supplier1ProductName AS ProductName, 'tblSupplier1' AS SourceTable, ThisFieldOnlyAppliesToSupplier1 FROM tblSupplier1
UNION
SELECT Supplier2ID AS ProductID, Supplier2ProductName AS ProductName, 'tblSupplier2' AS SourceTable, NULL AS ThisFieldOnlyAppliesToSupplier1 FROM tblSupplier2
```

You can add any additional fields/table and save it as a query. The only hiccup is if the ProductID's may conflict between tables then you have to generate unique IDs (possibly prefix with a short identifier for each linked table)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of UNION, I'll have to do some research on it to understand how that works.
Is it possible to generate the unique id prefix in the query?  Or would it have to be done with a composite key in the table?

Comment: Sure, just for example use `"Prefix1-" & Supplier1ID AS ProductID`. If any of the SupplierID's are numerical you can use `CStr(Supplier1ID)`